# GCP Development Server - VM accessible to only one person

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I want to automate the creation of development servers within my org's GCP account that are tied to an individual developer.

I intend to script the copying of relevant credentials (think crypto key for GitHub). How do I lockdown the VM so that only a single user can access it. GCP has options like `block-project-ssh-keys` but we've found that all users are still able to login using `gcloud compute ssh`.

I fear this may require a really complex IAM configuration.

1. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? (IAM or otherwise)
2. Has anyone seen a project that has automated this or something similar to this? (IAM provisioning of a new tag/group/etc. using a script when a new user joins the org)

Comment: Yes, this can be done on a per Compute Engine VM instance. 1) Remove all roles that grant permissions to Compute Engine. 2) Add the desired identities to the VM's IAM policy. This link will help: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/managing-access-to-resources 3) Another option is to remove all access to a VM and then issue SSH keys to each user. They can log into the instance via SSH but cannot use the GUI.

Comment: 4) There are many ways to access a VM. There are several ways to limit access. This includes IAM, IP based restrictions, VPNs, etc. Make sure that you understand how to manage and limit access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restricting user access for VM in gcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60503871/restricting-user-access-for-vm-in-gcp) or [How to give access to single Compute Instance on GCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756755/how-to-give-access-to-single-compute-instance-on-gcp) ...it's all about the [search terms](https://www.google.com/search?q=IAM+limit+access+per+vm+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I have attempted `enable-oslogin=FALSE`, `block-project-ssh-keys=TRUE`, and metadata ssh-keys. However, after startup I am still able to login use gcloud. `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` reads "Added by Google\n...".

Answer (score 4):

1. Enable [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin) on the project, ideally by using an organizational policy constraint. OS Login automatically disables metadata-based SSH keys.
2. Grant [OS Login roles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#grant-iam-roles) individually per VM and user so that each user can only login to their own VM.
3. Either don't attach service accounts to the VMs at all, or create dedicated service accounts per VM. Then grant users the *Service Account user* role on "their" service account only.
4. Don't grant any *Compute** roles beyond *Compute Viewer* on the project. In particular, don't grant *Compute Admin* or *Compute Instance Admin*, or any other role that lets users modify instance metadata (because that would let them alter startup and shutdown scripts).

Optionally:

3. Grant the users *Compute Viewer* on the project. That ensures that they can list VMs in the Cloud Console.
4. Only allow SSH access via [IAP TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding), and grant the *IAP-secured tunnel user* role on a per-VM, per-user basis.